# Laravel chain method in creating a record with multiple models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

Hello how can I chain a method create using eloquent? I want to create 3 records in one query. What I currently have is

```
        $role = ($input['role'] == 'creator') ? 'creator' : 'sponsor';
        $user->$role()->create([
            'plan_id' => 1,
            'name' => $input['name']
        ]);
```

But I cant create a role either a sponsor or creator since the table sponsor and creator has this `plan_id` column that is referencing to `account_plans` table. Is it possible to create a plan first before the role?

I have an error of

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'plan_id' doesn't have a default value
(SQL: insert into `creators` (`name`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (Juan, 1, 2023-02-22 11:18:21, 2023-02-22 11:18:21))"
```

Here are the 3 models that I used

```
class Sponsor extends Model
{

    public function plans(){
        return $this->hasOne(AccountPlan::class);
    }
}

class Creator extends Model
{

    public function plans(){
        return $this->hasOne(AccountPlan::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    public function sponsor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Sponsor::class);
    }

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Creator::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: add a default value and update it later

Comment: did you include the `plan_id` in the `$fillable` ?

Comment: yes i included it @xenooooo

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help you!

**Laravel 9**

```
 Model1::create()->each(function($model1) {
     Model2::create(['foreign_id' => $model1->id])->each(function($model2) {
          Model3::create(['foreign_id' => $model2->id]);
     });
 });
```